# Solving recurrence relation T(n) = T(n-1) + n

Tags: iteration, relation, recurrence

I see from a previous answer to this question, the person gave:

T(n) = T(n-2) + n-1 + n

T(n) = T(n-3) + n-2 + n-1 + n

T(n) = T(n-k) +kn - k(k-1)/2

I'm not understanding completely the third line.  I can see they may have derived it from arithmetic series formula summation of 1/2n(n+1)?  But how did they get kn and the minus sign in front of k(k-1)/2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

starting from:

```
T(n) = T(n-2) + n-1 + n
```

we may rewrite it as follows:

```
T(n) = T(n-2) + 2n - 1
```

The second formula says:

```
T(n) = T(n-3)+n-2+n-1+n
```

let us convert it the same way we do with the first one:

```
T(n) = T(n-3)+n+n+n-2-1
T(n) = T(n-3)+3n-2-1
```

By expanding more terms, we notice that the number subtracted from n in the recursive term:T(n-3) is always the same as the number multiplied by n. we may rewrite it as follows:

```
T(n) = T(n-k)+kn+...
```

we also notice that -2 -1 is the arithmetic series but negated and stars from k-1. the arithmetic of k-1 is **(k-1)*k/2** just like **n(n+1)/2**. so the relation would be

```
T(n) = T(n-k)+kn-(k-1)*k/2 or T(n) = T(n-k)+kn-k*(k-1)/2
```

Hope this help ;)

Comment: Why starting from k-1 and why negated?  Because numbers are getting smaller?

Comment: let us take the following:
T(n) = T(n-3) +3n -2-1
that is equal to:
T(n) = T(n-3)+3n-(2+1) is that alright?
we see now (2+1) is the summation of (k-1) k in this case is 3.
we may go further, to do:
T(n)=T(n-4) +4n - 3-2-1
which is T(n) = T(n-4) +4n- (3+2+1) k in this case is 4.

Comment: Yes I see how T(n) = T(n-3) + 3n-3.  But then how exactly did you turn 3n-3 into k(k-1)?

Comment: You're plugging in I/2(k-1)(k-1+1) into the arithmetic series summation?

Comment: yes, you are right. I am converting any term after kn into a summation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154054/discussion-between-maged-saeed-and-jean).

Comment: I believe I got it now.  Thanks so much!

Comment: If the answer was helpful for you, please accept it. This is a good practice for both of us.
best wishes.
:)
^_^

Comment: So basically the arithmetic series is 4 + 3 + 2 +1 instead of 1 + 2 + 3 +4?

Comment: Yes, they are also equivalent. But do not forget the negative sign.

Comment: like - (4 + 3 + 2 + 1) ?

Comment: Yes. That is true I guess.

Answer (score 1):

The `k(k-1)/2` term is just the sum of the numbers 0 to k-1. You can see why you need to subtract it from the following calculation:

```
T(n) = 
T(n-k) + n + (n-1) + (n-2) + ... + (n-(k-1)) =
T(n-k) + (n-0) + (n-1) + (n-2) + ... + (n-(k-1)) =
T(n-k) + n + n + n + ... + n - 0 - 1 - 2 ... - (k-1) =
T(n-k) + kn - (0 + 1 + 2 + ... + (k-1)) =
T(n-k) + kn - k*(k-1)/2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look closly:

```
T(n) = T(n-2) + n-1 + n = T(n-2) + 2n -1
T(n)= T(n-3) + n-2 + n-1 + n = T(n-3)+ 3n -(2+1) 
.
.
.
T(n)= T(n-k) + n-(k-1) + n-(k-2) + ... + n = T(n-k) + K * n + (-1 -2 - ... -(k-2) -(k-1))= T(n-k) + kn - k(k-1)/2
```

You can use recurrence theorem to demonstrate it